# Xslt - How to use Xpath to check Self-Closing tag in xml

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there any way to check self-closing tag in xslt. How to use XPath for that

Here what the XML file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <catalog>
     <cd>
        <title>1999 Grammy Nominees</title>
        <title>2000 Grammy Nominees</title>
    </cd>
    <cd><entry/>
        <title>2010 Grammy Nominees</title>
        <title>2011 Grammy Nominees</title>
    </cd>
</catalog
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />

 <xsl:template match="/catalog">      
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
  
 <xsl:template match="cd"> 
  <xsl:if test="cd and cd[not(entry)]>
    <xsl:for-each select="cd/title">  
      <fo:block background-color="red">      
          <xsl:value-of select=".">
      </fo:block>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd/entry"> // cd[entry]
    <xsl:for-each select="cd/title">  
      <fo:block background-color="blue">      
        <xsl:value-of select=".">
       </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can i check the self closing tag `<entry />` in xslt

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to check the tag (element)?

Comment: yeah I want to check <entry>( self closing tag )  is available or not

Comment: In terms of the XSLT/XPath XDM data model the markup `<entry></entry>` is for an empty `entry` element, you can't distinguish it in XPath from an empty `entry` element marked up as e.g. `<entry/>` or `<entry />`. You can of course check e.g. `entry[not(node())]` to check whether the context node has such an empty `entry` element as a child node.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing (!) you're trying to do something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/catalog"> 
    <fo:root>     
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:root>     
</xsl:template>
  
 <xsl:template match="cd"> 
    <xsl:for-each select="title">  
        <fo:block background-color="red">      
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd[entry]">
    <xsl:for-each select="title">  
        <fo:block background-color="blue">      
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As noted in the comments, the predicate `[entry]` tests for the existence of a child `entry` element  - whether self-closed or not.

Answer (score 1):

XPath cannot distinguish `<entry/>` from `<entry></entry>` - as far as the XPath data model is concerned, they are just two different ways of writing the same thing. Similarly, `<entry  />` and `<entry  ></entry  >` will also be indistinguishable.

You can test for an empty `entry` element with the predicate `entry[not(child::node())]`. This will match all four of the above examples. It will also match `<entry id="xyz"/>` - if you want to exclude attributes you need `entry[not(child::node()) and not(@*)]`.